# How to find pen pals?

Tags: learning

How do you find pen pals for people like me who are learning German and think maybe it'd be a good idea to have someone as a  pen pal who is a native German?

Comment: Are you looking for traditional mail or e-mail?

Comment: @TimN:  Both will do..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the German language.

Answer (score 3):

There is a [website of the Ruhr-Universität Bochum](http://www.slf.ruhr-uni-bochum.de) where you can easily find a tandem partner for example for email-conversations. This was very useful for me.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a penpal site like http://www.penpalpassport.com to find a language exchange partner. I'm learning English so if you want to practice then I'm happy.

Comment: Thanks for adding another site! However, while I appreciate your intention to learn English, that part of your question is probably better off in a comment.