# Test german writing skills

Tags: word-usage, word-order, writing

Is there any website or forum to test German writing skills?

Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: maybe related http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26883/how-might-i-find-somebody-to-provide-feedback-on-my-writing/26893#26893

Comment: How about being a little active + german.stackexchange.com ?