# Penpal website or people to write German with

Tags: german-to-english

I've been looking around for website for penpals to practice and learn German with, however, it seems like a lot of the website come up short. Any good links to find people?

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3453/how-to-find-pen-pals/6916#6916

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called "Tandem", I've heard you can talk to people speaking another language there. I have not tried it out for myself, but have been interested to try.

Answer (score -1):

Not a website, and only for iOS.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/willow-branch-out/id903479248?mt=8

It's an app where you can pose questions that get answered by others and vice versa.